# Javascript - cannot trigger event in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mouseevent, eventtrigger

I am using [polyfills](https://polyfill.io) for legacy browsers, but IE doesn't dispatch and further more I get an error such as `SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action`

```
//define the event
var myEv = new Event('mouseout');

//trigger it when it's the case
self.element.dispatchEvent(myEv);
```

Can anyone please give some working example or a fix with a small explanation.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add an event listener to `self.element` listening for your new Event.

```
self.element.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    alert(e);
});
```

I wrote an example for a similar question here: http://jsfiddle.net/4z891LwL/

Comment: Did you test this in IE? It does same thing with or without the `addEventListener` handler.

Comment: The answer lies with the MSDN docs here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975247(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-1